# Почему не работает условие скрытия?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Если сузить экран и нажать на .click-wrapp-curtain то блок .wrapp-curtain скроется. И если расширить экран то блок .wrapp-curtain по идее должен появиться ведь стоит условие

```js
if($('.click-wrapp-curtain').is(':hidden') && $('.wrapp-curtain').is(':hidden')) {
     $('.wrapp-curtain').css('display', 'block')
    }
```

Почему этого не происходит? Если сузить экран и скрыть его и потом расширить то он не появляется

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {   
    
$('.click-wrapp-curtain').click(function(){
     $('.wrapp-curtain').slideToggle();
    });
   
if($('.click-wrapp-curtain').is(':hidden') && $('.wrapp-curtain').is(':hidden')) {
     $('.wrapp-curtain').css('display', 'block')
    }
   
    });
```

```css
.click-wrapp-curtain{
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width : 480px) {
    .click-wrapp-curtain {
    display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="click-wrapp-curtain">werew</p>
<div class="wrapp-curtain">5465465465465465</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xsg64h7m

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что метод jQuery .is() Не является событием и он выполняется всего один раз - при загрузке DOM.

Вам следует смотреть в сторону события [.resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.click-wrapp-curtain').click(function() {
    $('.wrapp-curtain').slideToggle();
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    var win = $(this);
    if (win.width() > 480) {
      if ($('.click-wrapp-curtain').is(':hidden') &&
        $('.wrapp-curtain').is(':hidden')) {
        $('.wrapp-curtain').css('display', 'block')
      }
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.click-wrapp-curtain {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .click-wrapp-curtain {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="click-wrapp-curtain">werew</p>
<div class="wrapp-curtain">5465465465465465</div>
```